# My Xcode4 cannot find CCRibbon

Tags: macos, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.2

I installed cocos2D 2.0 beta on my Mac.

But, my Xcode4 cannot find the class of CCRibbon.

So, I look for CCRibbon in the templates, but there is no CCRibbon.

Maybe it's an unstable version I think, but I'm not sure.

How can I use CCRibbon on my Xcode?

Do I install old version of cocos2D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2D 2.0 beta does not include CCRibbon, but v1.x does.

I'm not aware of any plans to re-add CCRibbon. I consider it unlikely that it will be added again because it's just one of the classes that were hardly used at all, and would require rewriting the class as a shader program.